Spin probabilities of a two electron system
In my lecture, an example was given, as to how we can calculate the probability that the x components of the spins of the two particles are both up. The result is:
$P(S_{1x}=\frac{\hbar}{2},S_{2x}=\frac{\hbar}{2})=|(\frac{1}{2}\langle +,+|+\langle -,+|+\langle -,-|,\langle +,-|)(\alpha|+,-\rangle)+\beta|-,+\rangle|^2$.
The initial state of the system is: $|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(\alpha|+,-\rangle+\beta|-,+\rangle)$.
And I don't understand the bra- expression here. I will start with the case of 1 electron, and I want, and believe it can be done(but not sure 100%), that the same logic to be applied when we consider a system of two electrons.
So for one electron the basis comprised of eigenstates of $L_z$ is : ($|+\rangle$,$|-\rangle$)
The system can be in an arbitrary state $|\psi\rangle$.
If I were to calculate the probability for measuring $\frac{\hbar}{2}$  for $S_z$, I would do:
$P(+\frac{\hbar}{2})=|\langle +|\psi\rangle|^2$
And If would want to find  the probability for measuring $\frac{\hbar}{2}$  for $S_x$, I would do:
$P(+\frac{\hbar}{2})=| _x\langle +|\psi\rangle|^2$, where $_x\langle +|=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|+\rangle +|-\rangle)$.
So, it's a simple projection to a basis ket element, that corresponds to the observable that we are measuring.
And the basis of the system of two electrons, is a tensor basis: $|+,+\rangle$,$|+,-\rangle$,$|-,+\rangle$ and $|-,-\rangle$.
The issue I am having is, how does the eigenstate of the x component of spin of the system looks like. Or better, what is the logic behind the derivation of the bra- expression in the RHS of $P(S_{1x}=\frac{\hbar}{2},S_{2x})$ ?

the question is unclear to me, what is the initial state, the one with arbitrary alpha and beta? is is written in  the x or the z spin basis?

@PatoGalmarini I edited the thread where I show the initial state of the system

ok, I got it now, they are writing it all in the z basis

Remember that (I add the letter for the basis for clarity):
$ |z_+>=1/\sqrt{2}(|x_+>+|x_->)$, and also that $ |x_+>=1/\sqrt{2}(|z_+>+|z_->)$
You can use this to write $|x_+x_+>$ in terms of the $|z_?z_?>'s$
If so you get:
$|x_+x_+>=1/2(|z_+z_+>+|z_+z_->+|z_-z_+>+|z_-z_->)$
which is the bra (well, I wrote the ket, but it is the same) you need to use with the state ket

Use \langle and \rangle for the angled brackets: $\langle$ and $\rangle$ look better than $>$ and $<$.

@march I agree, I just sacrificed beauty in exchange of speed
